# Is ASP.NET's default recommendation of registering dependencies in the Web project bad practice?

Tags: architecture

Something that's bugged me for years now about ASP.NET (Core) is that it's standard practice to set up dependency injection in the Web project, whether through the `Startup` class's `ConfigureServices` method or through the newer `WebApplication.CreateBuilder`'s `.Services.Add...` style.

I recently experimented with adding the following to my `Directory.Build.props` file to get back to the old style non-transitive project/package references:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <PackageReference>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

And it brought this issue into even greater focus, because in my `Startup` file, I now had an error: it couldn't access `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` which it needed in `ConfigureServices` to inject `SqlConnection` into DI.  This is but one example.  I'd need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` for my Web project to get this working again.  But should I?  Isn't this highlighting the fact that setting up DI in the Web project is inappropriate?

As far as I'm aware, presentation-layer projects shouldn't have direct access to stuff like `SqlClient` either in an n-tier architecture or in an onion architecture.  Why is it standard practice for ASP.NET projects to give the Web project access to everything - allowing the Web project to easily directly access packages that it shouldn't access - so that it can register DI dependencies, instead of having a separate bootstrap project that does it instead?

Is the default setup of all ASP.NET projects implementing bad practice just for the convenience of having 1 web project instead of 2 projects for web, and bootstrap / DI setup?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: How do you define "bad practice?"  What peril does your described scenario cause, if the Web project *only has global access* to everything for purposes of standing up the DI container, while the container provides access and lifetime control thereafter?

Comment: Easily being able to reference stuff that you shouldn't?  I thought architecture was partially about making it difficult to make mistakes.  Otherwise why not just stick everything into one big project?

Comment: I've been working on a Blazor project for several months now, and unless I need to add something to the DI container, I never touch that file.  It's not a question of discipline; I simply have no need.  Everything goes through the container.  Maybe hire folks that know what they're doing?

Comment: It's not that file, it's the entire project that gets access to the dependencies.  Also, why are you assuming Blazor?

Comment: Sigh, well I'm not in the heads of the folks who designed ASP.NET, so I can't really comment on their thought process.

Comment: The Dependency Injection pattern typically involves a [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) where all dependencies are managed *'as close to the application’s entry point as possible. '*

Comment: @BenCottrell Interestingly, that part of the book sails close to my feeling that the composition root should be in a separate project: "You can move the User Interface Layer out of the application’s root project. Advantage of this is that you can prevent the project that holds the User Interface Layer from taking a dependency on for instance the Data Access Layer project. This makes it impossible for UI classes to depend on Data Access classes." - but it stops short of really recommending it, presumably because it might be too tricky? Still confusing. I'd like to talk to the book's author!

Comment: @Jez As far as I'm aware ASP.NET Core (as of 6.0 onwards) now allows all Razor/cshtml/MVC/UI code to exist in separate assemblies away from the entry point by using the MSBuild Razor SDK - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-7.0.   (Something which historically was very difficult and under the old .NET Framework 4.x variants of ASP.NET.  Mark Seemann's book predates modern ASP.NET Core so some of his observations about ASP.NET may not be so true any more)

Comment: How is this related to DI? This to me seems more related to NuGet and it's transitive dependencies. It just got exposed because the DI code is using something from transitive NuGet dependency. I'm sure you can replicate this issue if you write your own code without DI.

Comment: Quick check shows that `SqlConnection` is inside `System.Data.SqlClient` . I don't see how would you expect to use `SqlConnection` without referencing `System.Data.SqlClient` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension method in the project that uses `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` that registers the dependencies.

Something like:

```
public static class ServicesConfiguration
{
    public static void AddDatabase(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
    }
}
```

In your startup simply call this method using `builder.services.AddDatabase()` which will only require a reference to the project and not the external dependencies of that project.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it standard practice for ASP.NET projects to give the Web
> project access to everything?

Because probably 90% of netcore web solutions just have the one web project.

Imagine if you had to make a console app as the entry point program, which then setup the DI and referenced your web project, which you had setup with some main class which took construction parameters for all the interfaces it needed.

Now imagine you want to make net core nice and simple for people to use. You just get rid of that startup project and put it's code in the web project.

But if you want to separate your views and controllers into a different project you can totally do that no probs.

Comment: Except that it's bad practice.  And if it were setup that way with a template, you wouldn't need to do it all manually anyway.

Comment: you say that, and obviously more projects = more good. but by your logic any single project code, even the simplest console app is bad?

Comment: you would be better off asking, should controllers go in a class lib? should html and javascript be separated into a different project as well? Yes, but if you have 50 lines of code total, do you really again anything?